# C++ : add & after auto type

Tags: c++

The code is

```
void functionName(vector<string>& words){
    for(auto &word : words){
    }
}
```

and I found if I change the code to this

```
void functionName(vector<string>& words){
   for(string word : words){
   }
```

}

the results are different.
The original question is 
What the differences between *auto &word* and *string word*?
Thank you very much for all the answers. I think I get the answer.

*auto &word* just like *string &word*. So the question can be translated into the differences between *string& word* and *string word*.
The difference between *string&* and *string* is reference or copy.

Comment: Are you asking the difference between `(auto &word : words)` and `(string word: words)`?  If so, there is a subtler difference.

Comment: Are you asking between `string &` and `auto &` or between plain `string` and `auto &`? Because in the latter case, besides automatic type deduction there's also the fact that `auto &` is a reference, while `string` will create a copy of the element.

Comment: `auto &word` translates to `std::string &word` and string is passed by reference, `std::string word` is just that and string is passed by value.

Comment: I think I get the answer and I will change my original question.Thank you very much for you help! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of auto& :](//stackoverflow.com/q/19414299/90527)

Answer (score 2):

Short: the difference in type determination. Usage of `string`will set it manually to `string` and usage of `auto` will lead to this:

> When declaring variables in block scope, in namespace scope, in
>   initialization statements of for loops, etc., the keyword auto may be
>   used as the type specifier.  Once the type of the initializer has been
>   determined, the compiler determines the type that will replace the
>   keyword auto using the rules for template argument deduction from a
>   function call (see template argument deduction#Other contexts for
>   details).

`&` and etc. modifiers:

> The keyword auto may be accompanied by modifiers, such as
>   const or &, which will participate in the type deduction. For example,
>   given const auto& i = expr;, the type of i is exactly the type of the
>   argument u in an imaginary template template void f(const U&
>   u) if the function call f(expr) was compiled. Therefore, auto&& may be
>   deduced either as an lvalue reference or rvalue reference according to
>   the initializer, which is used in range-based for loop.

[auto cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)

[Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction)